# Kernel panics randomly

Tags: 13.04, kernel, 64-bit

My system randomly crashes. I cannot reproduce the crash except using this command:

```
echo c | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Everytime it crashes (like once a week). I can boot and work with the machine, but at some point it crashes. I did the normal kernel updates and installed and uninstalled several things. This did not affect the problem.

Ich am using 13.04 64bit. Here is the link to the [syslog of the time of the crash](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5784571/)

So, any suggestions? I do not even know if it is a software or hardware problem...

The system:

Samsung NP530U3C-A0B with Intel Core i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4

Graphics:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0d7]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

BIOS information:

```
Vendor: Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
Version: P01ABH
Release Date: 08/21/2012
Address: 0xE0000
Runtime Size: 128 kB
ROM Size: 3072 kB
```

Hardware information:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

[image: Screenshot of the panic]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what the specifications of your computer are?

Comment: Sure, what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Model name, processor, graphics card, etc.

Comment: Check it out now. :)

Comment: If you have time for it, run a memory test. Often random crashes are caused by broken memory. I'm not an expert regarding the Kernel, but it seems to me your crash occured during memory allocation, what might hint towards this. Memtest86 should be included on most Linux installation CD's.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't had the time to run memtest, but I do it tonight. If it was the broken memory I should send the laptop back ;)